# How to get component type of a Reacy lazy component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, react-server-components

I am using Next.js 13 and React Server Components.

I have a component `Block` that acts as a parent to other `Block`-kind children, which it switches on like this:

```js
export function Block({ children }) {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="m-5">
      {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
        if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
          console.error("invalid Block child", child);
          return null;
        }
        switch (child.type) {
          case BlockHeading:
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
              visible,
              onClick: () => setVisible(!visible)
            });
          case BlockBody:
            return React.cloneElement(child, { visible });
          default:
            console.error("invalid Block child", child);
            return;
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I use the `Block` components within a React Server Component then the `child.type` of the children are an object like this:

```
{ 
  $$typeof: Symbol(react.lazy),
  type: { ... },
  ...
}
```

I guess Next.js and/or React is doing some clever stuff to change my components to be lazily loaded when I use them in a React Server Component.

How can I maintain this switch case on the child type when the `child.type` field is not preserved?

Answer (score 0):

The object produced for a React lazy component looks something like this (many properties have been excluded for brevity):

```
{
  $$typeof: Symbol(react.element),
  type: {
    $$typeof: Symbol(react.lazy),
    _payload: {
      value: {
        name: "BlockHeading"
      }
    }
  },
}
```

With this it is possible to obtain the name of a lazy component from `type._payload.value.name`.

So we can update the switch statement to switch on the name of components rather than their identity:

```
// Get the name of the child component
const type =
  "_payload" in child.type
    ? child.type._payload.value.name // Lazy
    : child.type.name; // Non-lazy

switch (type) {
  case "BlockHeading":
    // ...
  case "BlockBody":
    // ...
}
```

Note that this answer is based on React internals that may change and so you should look at alternative, more idiomatic ways of sharing state with children, such as [React Context](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext).